# docker-credential-desktop not installed or not available in PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose, homebrew, docker-machine

I might have a bit of a messed Docker installation on my Mac..
At first I installed Docker desktop but then running it I learned that as I'm on an older Mac I had to install VirtualBox so I did following these steps:

1. enable writing on the `/usr/local/bin` folder for user

   `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin`
2. install Docker-Machine

```sh
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine &&
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

3. install Xcode CLI..manually from dev account
4. Install Home Brew

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

5. Install  Docker  + wget ( Using Brew)

   `brew install docker`

   `brew install wget`
6. Install bash completion scripts

```sh
base=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/machine/v0.16.0
for i in docker-machine-prompt.bash docker-machine-wrapper.bash docker-machine.bash
do
    sudo wget "$base/contrib/completion/bash/${i}" -P /etc/bash_completion.d
done
```

7. enable the docker-machine shell prompt

   `echo 'PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$ '' >> ~/.bashrc`
8. Install VirtualBox, ExtensionPack and SDK: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

I now installed docker-compose (docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown) with home-brew but when running `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

> `docker.credentials.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-desktop not installed or not available in PATH`

`which docker` prints /usr/local/bin/docker.

Brew installations are in `/usr/local/Cellar/docker/20.10.6` and `/usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.29.2`.
As I see there is also a home-brew for docker-machine should I install docker-machine via home-brew instead?

What can I check to make sure that I use the docker installations from home-brew and wipe/correct the installations made from steps above?

Comment: Can you try [this solution](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3785#issuecomment-518620870)?

Comment: @NickODell I didi try it and didn't work.. but I found out what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: You meant the `ln -s "/Applications/Docker.app/Contents//Resources/bin/docker-credential-desktop" "/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop"` command? I'm not running the app.. The post before it actually say what's the correct credStore value is depending on Docker version.. in my case  is `Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289`

Comment: Same problem on WSL2/Ubuntu.  The correct solution for WSL2 can be found in the [link]{https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3785#issuecomment-642210534} (thanks  [Nick ODell]{https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell}).  All the other answers below are dangerous.

Comment: Same issue on WSL2/Ubuntu.  @NickODell pointed to the correct thread.  For WSL2 the answer is in this [link](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3785#issuecomment-642210534).  Almost all the answers below seem to be dangerous.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After a long googling I found out that the problem is with the `config.json` file.
The `"credsStore" : "docker-credential-desktop"` is wrong one in :

```
{
  "credsStore" : "docker-credential-desktop",
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "experimental" : "disabled"
}
```

changed the `"credsStore"` key value to `"desktop"` and compose now works as expected. Some pointed out that `credsDstore` typo was the problem and fixed it with `credDstore`, but in my case the value was the problem, it works both with `"credsStore" : "desktop"` and `"credStore" : "desktop"`.

Hope it'll help others starting out with Docker.
Cheers.

Comment: I was looking for location of `config.json`. In my case it was `~/.docker/config.json`. General documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#docker-cli-configuration-file-configjson-properties

Comment: `"credsStore: "desktop"` was the default value for a fresh install of Docker, version `Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414`.  @Ivan's answer of changing `credsStore` (plural) to `credStore` (singular) did indeed fix the issue for me.

Comment: This just turns off the credentials.  The answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888813/5445739) is correct.

Comment: or delete the entire credStore line

Answer (score 288):

Check your `~/.docker/config.json` and replace "credsStore" by "credStore"

```
{
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "experimental" : "disabled",
  "credStore" : "desktop"
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed that was the problem as I already found out and published in my answer,  but thanks for answering. Cheers.

Comment: `~/.docker/config.json` this is a file path to be precise

Comment: This solution worked fine for me on macOS Catalina.

Comment: 2022 August. I'm running docker Engine 20.10.17 on Mac Monterey with colima 0.4.4, no docker desktop. Changing `"credsStore": "desktop"` to `"credStore": "desktop" helped me solve the following problem with docker login:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``
```

Comment: Note that `credStore` is not a valid config key (please correct me if I am wrong), so the only reason changing `credsStore` to `credStore` works is because you are effectively deleting the `credStore` entry. IMO it's better to just delete it, or rename it to something obviously placeholder, so that it's not misleading in future if you are reviewing your config.

Comment: For users on [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima), you can set the value of `credStore` to `colima`.

Comment: Worked fine for me on Windows 10 WSL (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS). Thanks!

Comment: It also works by deleting the `credsStore` entry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888813/10215243 -- this is the real fix, other's are a hack/workaround.

Comment: This is really strange how I had to change this while i "only threw away some containers"... anyway. It worked on my Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This also works for WSL2

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you! How come the config is generated with the wrong spelling for that property?

Comment: Was also the case with Linux. Installed Docker Desktop for Linux, had an issue with USB not routing through to my container. Removed Desktop and went direct to engine. Same issue with creds vs cred.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. On MacOS Sonoma

Answer (score 93):

In `~/.docker/config.json` just change **`credsStore`** to **`credStore`**

Comment: Ivan if you check my own answer ( the accepted one ) you'll see that it works with credsStore too.. the problem was tha value..nit the key

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS7. My error was `docker.credentials.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-pass not installed or not available in PATH` when I ran `docker-compose up -d`. Thanks @Ivan.

Comment: This solved my issue, too. It was the key that was wrong, not the values in my case.

Comment: Note that, as far as I know, this solution is misleading: it works because `credStore` is not a valid key, and is ignored by Docker. It's equivalent to removing `"credsStore": "desktop"`, which I would argue is better because if you are debugging your config in future to determine why Docker is not resolving credentials, it will be easy to miss the typo.

Comment: Me too. @Vicenzo: I tried what you said, it is wrong. The key, in my case, has to be credStore.

Comment: This is incorrect and dangerous. It turns off the credentials store.  The correct answer is [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888813/5445739)

Answer (score 43):

Since you're on a Mac, you could use `docker-credential-osxkeychain` instead.

1. Install `docker-credential-helper`.

   ```bash
   brew install docker-credential-helper
   ```
2. Verify `docker-credential-osxkeychain` is available.

   ```bash
   $ docker-credential-osxkeychain version
   0.6.4
   ```
3. Set `credsStore` to `osxkeychain` in `~/.docker/config.json`

   ```json
   {
     "auths": {
       "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
     },
     "credsStore": "osxkeychain",
     "experimental": "enabled",
     "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
   }
   ```
4. Login to Docker Hub.

   ```bash
   $ docker login -u $USER
   Password: 
   Login Succeeded
   ```

Comment: This is the correct and the safest answer so far. In the above, all answers are bypassing the dynamic credentials. Using the binary of docker-credential-osxkeychain ensures that the credentials of the docker login are not stored in plaintext format.

Comment: This worked for me.  I don't know the version check, but after setting my docker config to the content supplied from number 3 above, I was up and running.

Comment: Should be accepted as best answer for mac

Comment: Installing only `docker-credential-helper` (i.e. step 1) made it work.

Comment: this is the correct answer. please see documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-stores

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue using wsl2 on windows 10 while trying to locally invoke an aws lambda function. I was getting `docker.credentials.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-desktop not installed or not available in PATH` when running `sam build --use-container`. Running `which docker-credential-desktop` showed no results

Upon further inspection I found that `docker-credential-desktop.exe` was in `PATH` however. After a quick google, it seems like enabling the wsl2 backend in Docker Desktop for Windows 10 symlinks `wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-credentials-desktop.exe` to `/usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe`. To fix this I simply removed the symlink and created a new one without `.exe`

To check the link and remove it:

```
user@device:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 67 Jan  5 23:15 /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe -> /wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe
user@device:~$ sudo rm /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe
```

To create a new one without `.exe` and check it worked:

```
user@device:~$ sudo ln -s /wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop
user@device:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 67 Jan 12 14:22 /usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop -> /wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-credential-desktop.exe
```

After that I sourced `.bashrc` to update `PATH` and the problem was resolved. I verified this with `which docker-credential-desktop` and it now shows the location specified in the symlink above.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down. Just wanted to note that on my system, `wsl` is mounted on `/mnt/wsl/`. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I think `/mnt/wsl` is the default mount location. I vaguely recall changing my configuration or creating a symlink when I installed wsl2 on my machine.

Comment: This is incorrect and can corrupt your installation.  The correct answer is in the link posted by @NickODell in the first comment.  For WSL, the answer is [here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3785#issuecomment-642210534)

Answer (score 1):

If your are on WSL, try `desktop.exe`, instead of `desktop`. Because you will find that the program in `/usr/bin/` is `docker-credential-desktop.exe`.

```
{
   "credsStore": "desktop.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned elsewhere, renaming `credsStore` to `credStore` just sets it to an invalid value and disables authorization.

I'm assuming my issue is because I have `docker-ce` installed & not `docker-desktop`. The solution I found was to build a credential helper from [their repo](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers).

I'm running a rootless install under Ubuntu, but some of the commands required root access, so I ended up running:

- `sudo systemctl start docker`
- `sudo docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all`
- `sudo docker buildx create --use`
- `git clone https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers.git`
- `cd docker-credential-helpers/`
- `make secretservice` `# secretservice uses the dbus secrets manager`
- `cp bin/build/docker-credential-secretservice ~/bin` `# ~/bin is on my $PATH`
- `cd ~/.docker/`
- `sed -e 's/"credsStore": "desktop"/"credsStore": "secretservice"/' config.json > config.json.new`
- `mv config.json.new config.json`